# Adding new element at top position of list-view android with cursor adapter.

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

Hi I am developing small android application in which i using list fragment. I this application what i want to do is fetch data from database and display it with `SimpleCursorAdapter` and after displaying data in list view I wanted to insert one dummy row at zero position of list which is not from database. My code structure looks like this

```
public class MyCards extends SherlockListFragment implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = null;
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .

private void displayCards() 
{
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getActivity(),R.layout.coupon, null, from, to, 0);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // now after this i want to display one dummy row at zero position 
}


}
```

How to do this. Need Help ...
Thank you.

Comment: It would be better if you show your code where you set data which is extracted from database to your adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve like, while filling your array from database, add one dummy data at zero position and then add your actual data from database, and set the array to listivew.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
getListView().setSelection(location);
```

Location is the postion,where you need to set the cursor

**EDIT 1**

```
private Vector<RowData> data;

try {

                            rd=new RowData(iTmp,demo[0], demo[1], demo[2],demo[3],demo[4]);

                        }

                        catch (ParseException e)

                        {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                        data.add(rd);

                        //data.add(tokens[iTmp]);

                    }
                    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.firstlist,R.id.title, data);
```

**EDIT 2**
Please check this Links

- [List View Tutorial
  1](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)
- [List View Tutorial
  2](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/)

Comment: Hi onkar thank you for quick reply.. I think so from this I set the cursor position but how to insert new dummy element in list view. I don't want to insert it into database just want to display that dummy row in list view only.

Comment: Pass the value to the constructor through your adapter.

Comment: I am not getting you. Is this modify my adapter as well? or just insert it into view

Comment: I have updated my answer, I suppose that it should work. ROWDATA is the class name.